# Parallelism and the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, parallel-processing, async-await

It's very common in our web applications to need data from a variety of tables in our database.  Today you might find 5 or 6 database queries being executed serially for a single request.  None of these queries depend on data from the other so they are perfect candidates for being executed in parallel.  The problem is the well known `DbConcurrencyException` which is thrown when multiple queries are executed against the same context.

We typically use a single context per request and then have a repository class so we can reuse queries across various projects.  We then dispose of the context at the end of the request when the controller is disposed.

Below is an example which uses parallelism, but there's still a problem!

```
var fileTask = new Repository().GetFile(id);
var filesTask = new Repository().GetAllFiles();
var productsTask = AllProducts();
var versionsTask = new Repository().GetVersions();
var termsTask = new Repository().GetTerms();

await Task.WhenAll(fileTask, filesTask, productsTask, versionsTask, termsTask);
```

Each repository is internally creating its own context, but as it is now, they aren't being disposed.  That's a problem.  I know I could call `Dispose` on each repository that I create, but that starts to clutter the code quickly.  I could create a wrapper function for each query which uses its own context, but that feels messy and isn't a great long term solution for the problem.

What would be the best way to address this problem?  I'd like the client/consumer to not have to worry about disposing each repository/context in the case of having multiple queries executed in parallel.

The only idea I have right now is to follow an approach similar to a factory pattern, except my factory would keep track of all the objects it created.  I could then dispose of the factory once I know my queries are finished and the factory could internally dispose of each repository/context.

I'm surprised to see such little discussion around parallelism and the Entity Framework, so hopefully some more ideas from the community will come in.

**Edit**

Here is a simple example of what our repository looks like:

```
public class Repository : IDisposable {
    public Repository() {
        this.context = new Context();
        this.context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public async Task<File> GetFile(int id) {
        return await this.context.Files.FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.Id == id);
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (!this.disposed) {
            if (disposing) {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

As you can see, each repository gets its own context.  This means that each repository needs to be disposed of.  In the example I gave above, that means I would need 4 calls to `Dispose()`.

My thoughts for a factory approach to the problem was something like the following:

```
public class RepositoryFactory : IDisposable {
    private List<IRepository> repositories;

    public RepositoryFactory() {
        this.repositories = new List<IRepository>();
    }

    public IRepository CreateRepository() {
        var repo = new Repository();
        this.repositories.Add(repo);
        return repo;            
    }

    #region Dispose
    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (!this.disposed) {
            if (disposing) {
                foreach (var repo in repositories) {
                    repo.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

This factory would be responsible for creating instances of my repository, but it would also keep track of all the instances it has created.  Once this single factory class is disposed of it would internally be responsible for disposing of each repository that it created.

Comment: I believe an EF context does not need to be disposed if you do not manage the connection manually. It should open and close for each request. Not disposing contexts strikes me as a dirty approach, though.

Comment: @usr We have code written by someone else in production that isn't disposing of all the contexts. :)  It works, but I'm not certain on what the consequences are or will be.  Since the context implements `IDisposable`, I'd like to develop an approach that removes the mystery of what might happen.

Comment: _"What would be the best way to address this problem?"_ -- I think you will need to be more specific about your objections to possible approaches you've already identified. Something better than "messy" and "clutter". Fact is, encapsulation is a common and valid technique for hiding "messy" and "clutter", and a wrapper of some sort is a form of encapsulation. Without more details, all you're going to get are vague, opinionated answers.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - Fair points.  My objections to writing a wrapper method for each repository method is that it feels awfully duplicated.  I'm curious to hear what people think of a factory-ish approach to handling this issue.  I think this question clearly shows what the problem is and what I'm trying to solve.  Software engineering comes with opinions on how to solve problems, so if someone has an opinion on how to best address the issue I would love to hear it.

Comment: It's not clear in your example where and when the context is created. You say you have a single context per request but also that each repository creates its own context?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted an example of what a "typical" Repository method looks like.

Comment: @ken2k Good point.  I added an example of the repository.

Comment: @ToddMenier I added an example of the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could allow clients to configure the disposal behavior of `Repository` by passing some sort of optional (false by default) `autodispose` bit to the constructor. An implementation would look something like this:

```
public class Repository : IDisposable
{
    private readonly bool _autodispose = false;
    private readonly Lazy<Context> _context = new Lazy<Context>(CreateContext);

    public Repository(bool autodispose = false) {
        _autodispose = autodispose;
    }

    public Task<File> GetFile(int id) {
        // public query methods are still one-liners
        return WithContext(c => c.Files.FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.Id == id));
    }

    private async Task<T> WithContext<T>(Func<Context, Task<T>> func) {
        if (_autodispose) {
            using (var c = CreateContext()) {
                return await func(c);
            }
        }
        else {
            return await func(_context.Value);
        }
    }

    private static Context CreateContext() {
        var c = new Context();
        c.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        return c;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if (_context.IsValueCreated)
            _context.Value.Dispose();
    }
}
```

*Note: I kept the disposal logic simple for illustration; you may need to work your `disposed` bits back in.*

Your query methods are still simple one-liners, and the client can very easily configure the disposal behavior as needed, and even re-use a Repository instance in auto-disposal situations:

```
var repo = new Repository(autodispose: true);
var fileTask = repo.GetFile(id);
var filesTask = repo.GetAllFiles();
var productsTask = AllProducts();
var versionsTask = repo.GetVersions();
var termsTask = repo.GetTerms();

await Task.WhenAll(fileTask, filesTask, productsTask, versionsTask, termsTask);
```

Comment: This is a good idea and it was initially how I thought I could solve this problem, but there are times where I can't have the context disposed because the record needs to be updated.  There are many situations where we query the existing record from the database, update the object with the new data from the user and commit those changes to the database.  If the context is disposed then the update would fail.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you need the behavior to be configurable, and based on that I re-wrote my answer. I still don't think there's any need for a Factory class here.

Comment: This looks good!  I'm not sure why I didn't think to move that bit to the constructor.  I gave you a +1 and I'll hopefully give this a try later this afternoon or next week.

Comment: A slight variation that occurred to me later would be to have a separate class (something like `ConcurrentRepository`) instead of the `autodispose` bit. Implementation would be similar to above, you'd just make `WithContext` protected virtual, implement it with just the shared context, and have `ConcurrentRepository` inherit from `Repository` and override `WithContext` with the `using` implementation. Same amount of DRY, only advantage would be if you think instantiating a different class is cleaner for the client than passing a constructor bit.

Comment: Thanks for your help Todd!  I was finally able to come back to this and it's working great.